# Boss asked if I want to join training for technology that I have no experience with

Tags: career-development, training

Yesterday my boss asked me if I'm interested to join a 4-day training session to be held overseas for a device that will involve Android programming. I have zero knowledge about Android, but still the boss asked me first if I want to join.

Now I am quite new to software development (2 years). I have only used C so far, and I have been thinking of looking for a new job that will allow me to use a new programming language. This training looks like a good chance for me  to learn a new technology. However I am wary of the training bond that comes with joining this training. I would have to stay in the company for at least 1 year after training and this thought makes me scared. I am also not confident if I can learn quickly, given the fast-paced nature of our company (multiple projects and extremely short timelines).

Should I take this training or not? And would it be a good idea to voice out these concerns to my boss? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, learning Android programming in four days would be like drinking from a high-pressure fire hose. If the training was free and came with no strings attached, I'd accept it, but in this case, I don't think you should do it, or at least you should delay the training date for a few months. This way, you could get yourself up to speed in Java or Kotlin, and you could start learning the basics of Android on your own time. And then you could start the training. Or you could find Android training that is more local to you, but that would be less condensed and that you could take each week.

Comment: The benefit of them requiring you to stay at least a year is that they won't fire you for at least a year.  Now granted, something else might happen, that results in yournlosing your job but it's less likely they will get rid of somebody if they spent money to train you (and some do they have required to commit to staying)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your choice. Do you want to stay at least one year with the company? That's one side. On the other side, the more you learn the better for you personally. And the company does this training for a reason. Your boss will divide employees into categories "willing to learn" and "not willing to learn", so you don't want to end up in the wrong category. And quite soon he or she might divide employees into categories "can do this job because of training / can't do this job because they refused training".

But then you say yourself you are looking for a new job that involves learning a new programming language. Here it seems that is exactly what is offered to you in your current job. And if this company wants you to stay for a year if you take the training, then the next company will likely ask for the same thing. So is your company a company where you would want to stay?

As far as not keeping up, get a book about Android and read it before the training. And going overseas for training would be an opportunity for many that they wouldn't want to miss.